# Prismatic Joint not working properly with ROS2 & Gazebo 11

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I posted this question on the [ROS forum](https://answers.ros.org/question/357993/prismatic-joint-not-working-properly-with-ros2-gazebo-11/?answer=358444#post-id-358444) as well but as I still haven't found the answer, I'll repost it here.

I have been trying to make a robot model with a prismatic joint which moves in z axis. It has a lift link and uses joint state to actuate the motion. The whole setup worked great with ROS1 and loading robot description from `.xacro` files (`x.urdf.xacro`, `x.transmission.xacro` and `x.gazebo.xacro`) with `spawn_urdf` form `gazebo_ros`

However, when I started porting the robot model for ROS2, I soon discovered that this no longer works properly and I had to create a standalone `sdf 1.5` file. I managed to get almost everything working in this format, except the prismatic lift joint. The lift platform keeps dropping to the floor if z axis unit vector is selected. If we use x or y axis, the platform is on the correct position, but sheers in x or y direction.

[image: ROS2 Robot]

[This](https://github.com/shreyasgokhale/CustomRobots/blob/foxy-devel/amazon_robot/amazon_robot_gazebo/models/amazon_robot2/model.sdf) is the link to my robot's model in ROS2 and [this](https://github.com/shreyasgokhale/CustomRobots/tree/melodic-devel/amazon_robot/amazon_robot_description/urdf) is the robot description from ROS1.

I am using [turtlebot3](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/ros2-devel/turtlebot3_gazebo/models) and [dolly](https://github.com/chapulina/dolly/tree/master/dolly_gazebo/models/dolly) as ideal examples of robots launching with gazebo in ROS2. The robot itself is based on turtlebot3 with 2x the size and additional lift joint.

What am I doing wrong here? Also, does anyone know any other ROS2 based gazebo models for such warehouse robots which I can refer to? Also, can we launch `.xacro` files using xacro plugin in ROS2?

Moreover, after investigation, I found out that if I disable gravity or apply any force which has an upward z component, the platform can go high up freely.

Thanks!

For reference: [this](https://youtu.be/4DCr3LRLVLE) is the video of my robot operating in ROS1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25618/prismatic-joint-not-working-properly-with-ros2-&-gazebo-11/) by [elementaryshr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29627/elementaryshr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> can we launch .xacro files using xacro plugin in ROS2?

Yes, `xacro` is available for Foxy. [Here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control/blob/d4f6e7079292b676ce2080bf0e6987531c2796e1/gazebo_ros2_control_demos/launch/cart_example_position.launch.py#L38-L44)'s an example using it.

> x.transmission.xacro

I see your robot is using transmissions. These are not directly supported by Gazebo, they're used by `ros_control` and used by Gazebo through `gazebo_ros_control`. See how your ROS 1 robot is using that [here](https://github.com/shreyasgokhale/CustomRobots/blob/b2c6c134817d641e35a896106be5f73198de2c28/amazon_robot/amazon_robot_description/urdf/amazon_warehouse_robot.gazebo.xacro#L168-L173).

`ros_control` hasn't been fully ported to ROS 2 yet. You can follow its development, and the development of the corresponding `gazebo_ros2_control` here:

- https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control
- https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control

> What am I doing wrong here?

I believe the problem is trying to use `ros_control`. I recommend you use the `gazebo_ros_force_system` plugin instead. See a demo [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/ros2/gazebo_ros/worlds/gazebo_ros_force_system_demo.world).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elementaryshr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29627/elementaryshr/) on 2020-08-14**:
Thanks a lot for the answer. The xacro example looks really interesting and I might try that in the future. For now, I was able to get the lift joint working using force system

```
ros2 service call /apply_joint_effort gazebo_msgs/srv/ApplyJointEffort '{joint_name: "lift_joint", effort: -2.0, start_time: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, duration: {sec: 2000, nanosec: 0} }'
```